# How do I change all Oracle profiles PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME to UNLIMITED?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, subquery

This query:

```
select distinct profile from dba_profiles;
```

Returns 3 rows:

- default
- default1
- default2.

I want to change the `PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME` for all these profiles to `UNLIMITED` with a single query or without manually passing the profile names in query.

Because I do not know how many profiles are there in the system, the number of profiles will vary. I have to execute this query in multiple systems.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do it in one query?  This seems like a very odd requirement.

Comment: Because I do not know how many profiles are there in the system, the number of profiles will vary. I have to execute this query in multiple systems.

Comment: That seems like a really bad idea to me.  If you're determined to do it, I'll post an answer...

Comment: Please be aware that changing the profiles does nothing to the existing expiry_date for your users.  The only time password_lifetime comes into play is when a user password is changed.  Also, I agree it seems like a bad idea.  If you have so many profiles that it is a serious problem to do them one at a time, then I'd question your use of profiles.

Comment: Thanks EdStevens, then I think, query to change the password_life_time should be included before the user creation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "query to change the password_life_time should be included before the user creation".  Surely you aren't creating a separate profile for each user!  A well designed DB should have only a small handful of profiles. I've never needed but 2 or 3 at most.  A default for most users, a second for sensitive users, like dBAs.  Maybe a third for ... I don't know what, offhand.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it in PL/SQL in a loop:

```
begin
  for c in (select distinct profile from dba_profiles)
  loop
    execute immediate 'alter profile ' || c.profile || ' limit password_life_time unlimited';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
  v_query varchar2(1024) := '';
BEGIN
FOR x IN (SELECT DISTINCT PROFILE FROM dba_profiles)
loop
  v_query := 'alter profile ' || x.PROFILE || ' limit password_life_time unlimited';
  execute immediate v_query;
end loop;
END;
/
```

Comment: A couple words/explanation would be better than just a piece of code alone.